# Best way to develop/deploy Magento 2

Tags: git, magento, deployment, vagrant

I'm looking for a way to quickly spin up a Magento ready local machine and to effectively deploy it in VPS a (I usually use DigitalOcean).

For the Magento VM, I found [Magestead](https://www.magestead.com/), which is kind of cool (although I'm having some minor issues with it), but I'd like a quick way of provisioning a DigitalOcean server with the same packages and configuration as Magestead VM. I'm pretty new to Vagrant and deployment strategies (I usually just manually configure the production server and *git pull* my repo). I also came across [vagrant-digitalocean](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-digitalocean) which seems promising, but I haven't been able to integrate it with Magestead yet.

Any other Vagrant box or strategy (Chef?) is appreciated. I'm kind of new and lost here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried packaged Magento 2 that is automatically deployed with a help of Jelastic PaaS? 
https://github.com/jelastic-jps/magento/tree/master/magento

You can get it pre-configured and installed to the cloud with NGINX or LiteSpeed server and MariaDB. And set up [automated update process from Git/SVN](https://docs.jelastic.com/git-svn-auto-deploy).

Answer (score 0):

whell exist many ways.

I like [SaltStack](https://saltstack.com/), check their [introduction in 10 min](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html)

*"WHAT IS SALT?
Salt is a different approach to infrastructure management, founded on the idea that high-speed communication with large numbers of systems can open up new capabilities. This approach makes Salt a powerful multitasking system that can solve many specific problems in an infrastructure."*

Start is hard, and i can't find a nice magento 2 formula, but their principe master - mignions, produce a solid infraestructure, you can control many machines, when your salt is ready the life is easy. 100% compatible with DigitalOcean check this [tuto](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/automated-provisioning-of-digitalocean-cloud-servers-with-salt-cloud-on-ubuntu-12-04) or [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/saltstack-infrastructure-installing-the-salt-master)

For Dev magento2 i like this [vagrant](https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers)

I will try magestead, seems interesting.